# AWS lambda node js return response

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

How do I return the response instead of console.log for the below code in aws lambda node js?

```
exports.handler = (event) => {
    const https = require('https')
    https.get('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Auckland&appid=2eff2787a2d43a56539784f59bb8698a&units=metric', (resp) => {
        let data = [];
        // A chunk of data has been recieved.
        resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
            data.push(chunk)
        });
        resp.on('end', () => {
            // console.log(data.toString())
            console.log(JSON.parse(data.toString()));

        });

    }).on("error", (err) => {
        console.log("Error: " + err.message);

    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The handler in the question doesn't `return` anything.

Further, https.get is async. We may use the newer syntax (async/await) instead of a callback, it will make the code simpler and easier to read:

```
const https = require('https');

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    try {
        const data = await https.get('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Auckland&appid=2eff2787a2d43a56539784f59bb8698a&units=metric');
        return data;
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm new to node js. So I will explain to you exactly what I need. I want to call this lambda from some other AWS product like Amazon Connect and this lambda should return back the results. How do I do that? If you could give me a sample code, that will be of a huge help.

Comment: @ArunNair the answer contains sample code, it should return the data! ;)